# Unable to submit a second form with jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery

I have two forms on a single page. Actually they're seperated pages but the page-content is loaded into several divs enabling a sliding-effect through pages.

In one div I have a small form with two text-inputs. I can submit it without a problem. At another div I have a contact form. It's using the same script for handling the form. The only thing changed is the #id from where the .submit() should be binded to.

For some reason I just can't get the second form to work. Is there a limitation on forms in a page (I know, it sounds stupid but I'm clueless here...)?

The forms look like :

```
<form id='form-1'>
..
</form>

<form id='form-2'>
..
</form>
```

The jQuery, within `$(document).ready(function(){});`

```
$("#gratis-proefles").submit(function(){
        var str = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type:   "POST",
            url:    "ajax.php?type=proefles",
            data:   str,
            success: function(result){ 
                $("#ResultAanvraagProefles").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){    
                    if(result == true)
                    {
                        $(this).html('<span style="color:#76c5f0;"><strong>Bedankt voor je aanvraag! We nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met je op om de gratis proefles in te plannen!</strong></span>');
                        $(":input", "#gratis-proefles")
                             .not(":button, :submit, :reset, :hidden")
                             .val("");                    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).html('<span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong>Om een gratis proefles aan te kunnen vragen is het verplicht om zowel je naam als je telefoonnummer op te geven.</strong></span>');
                    }                         
                });
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

    $("#contact-formulier").submit(function(){
        var str = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type:   "POST",
            url:    "ajax.php?type=contact",
            data:   str,
            success: function(result){ 
                $("#ResultContact").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){    
                    if(result == true)
                    {
                        $(this).html('<span style="color:#76c5f0;"><strong>Bedankt voor je bericht! We nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met je op!</strong></span>');
                        $(":input", "#contact-formulier")
                             .not(":button, :submit, :reset, :hidden")
                             .val("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).html('<span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong>Alle velden zijn verplicht in te vullen.</strong></span>');
                    }                         
                });
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

A live example can be found on [http:vfw.ontdek5.nl/index.php](http://vfw.ontdek5.nl/index.php). It's in Dutch but the forms are on the pages 'Gratis Proefles' and 'Contact'.

Comment: On the second form submit callback do alert and return

Comment: Well, it never came in the jQuery function. .live() seemed to be the solution. Thanks for trying (I saw ur testingmail passing by ;)) +1 for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jquery live functionality for dynamically loaded forms!

```
jQuery.live();
```

Comment: It was the solution after all ;) I just forgot the rename a formID back to its binded name. Thanks all! +1 and accepted

Answer (score 2):

I can see in the HTML on the example site that your form has an ID of 'contact-formuliers' but in your code it's 'contact-formulier'. The problem could be as simple as that...

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I'd replaced the name because I also tested with the exact same form as from the Gratis Proefles page. In combination with .live(); it was the solution. I forgot to rename the form back :/.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in second id

`contact-formulier` should be `contact-formuliers`

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I'd replaced the name because I also tested with the exact same form as from the Gratis Proefles page. In combination with .live(); it was the solution. I forgot to rename the form back :/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quiet sure how your second form is being pulled into page but it sounds like an event is not binded as its being added to the page after the page has been loaded. Seeing as you using jquery 1.5 try use .delegate (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)but at a higher level and in your case try something like $('#slider').delegate('input:submit','click',function(event){}); You can then pick up which submit button was clicked and then find the form and submit that form.